# Android fetch all contacts duplicated names

Tags: android, contacts

Im using this code:

```
protected String getContactInfo() {
         Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
         String str = "";
         while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
          str += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)) + ", ";
        }
        cursor.close();
        return str;
}
```

and after execution the string that this method returns is Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test1, Test2, Test2, Test2, Test2, Test2, Bob, Bob, Bob, Bob,

When I have only 3 contacts in the phonebook Test1, Test2, Bob

Why would this happen?

Comment: Does each contact only have one number, or does "Bob" for instance have Home, Work, Email, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this...

replace the query parameter with URI...

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

you are trying to fetch the name from `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` and you are firing the query on `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`.